# What is the FragmentManager that is passed into FragmentStatePagerAdapter for?

Tags: android

I have been trying to figure out what the `FragmentManager` argument is actually for in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. In the documentation, no method actually utilizes it. Its purpose is also missing from the documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html#FragmentStatePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager)

The description of the constructor is actually blank, and none of the implementations of any of its methods require use of the `FragmentManager`.

What is the `FragmentManager` for?

(I know what `FragmentManager` is used for in other contexts, just not in the context of this adapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the FragmentManager for?

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` deals with `Fragment`s. As you would do in your `Activity`, where you would use the `FragmentManager` to `beginTransaction()` and commit it, the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` does the same. At a certain point, it will call `beginTransaction`, using the `FragmentManager` you provided to the super constructor, will call `getItem()`, where you return the `Fragment`s you want to show, and commit it. As pointed out by [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` takes care also to remove the `Fragment`s.

Comment: Specifically, it uses `FragmentTransactions` to add and remove pages. `FragmentPagerAdapter` only adds pages; `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will both add and remove pages (the latter to limit how many outstanding pages there are, to help keep a lid on heap consumption). You can see this in [the source code to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v13/java/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java), for example.

Comment: if i truly speak , you two master minds are really an amazing source of Android and Java knowledge..! thanks for helping us out.! :)

Comment: @Blackbelt So, in my code, if I set up the `Fragment`s I want to use in the `FragmentManager`, then pass it to the adapter, will there be any sort of assignment collision when I attempt to retrieve the `Fragment` from the manager?

Comment: depends on what you mean by *assignment collision*. If you are not using directly a `transaction` on those, and you are simply returning them in `getItem` then there shouldn't be any *collision*

Comment: @Blackbelt That's what I thought. I guess I'm having a different problem than I suspected. Thanks for your answer, I'll ask my other question separately. I'll be accepting this one as soon as the timer is up.

Comment: No, at runtime I get a `Fragment already added` error. But I don't do any assignments other than the initial one.

Comment: Yes, I'll post another question. Apparently I can only make one post every 90 minutes, so it might be a little while.